# Laravel define a put/patch route as the same route name

Tags: php, laravel-4, routes

In Laravel it's quite handy to quickly generate a load of routes by using a route resource:

```
Route::resource('things'ThingsController');
```

This will produce all the necessary RESTful routes for CRUD operations. One of these is the PUT/PATCH route which might be defined as follows:

```
PUT/PATCH things/{id} ThingsController@update things.update
```

I've read around that it's better to explicitly define each of your routes rather than use a route resource but how would I define the PUT/PATCH route above. I understand that I can do

```
Route::put('thing/{id}', ['as' => 'things.update']);
```

or

```
Route::patch('thing/{id}', ['as' => 'things.update']);
```

But the second would overwrite or conflict with the first allowing the `things.update` route name to only refer to either a PUT or PATCH request. How can I explicitly create the combined PUT/PATCH route as created by the resource route?

Answer (score 15):

After tedious searching, try the following;

```
Route::match(array('PUT', 'PATCH'), "/things/{id}", array(
      'uses' => 'ThingsController@update',
      'as' => 'things.update'
));
```

This allows you to restrict request via an array of Verbs.

Or you can limit the resource as so;

```
Route::resource('things', 'ThingsController',
        array(
           'only' => array('update'), 
           'names' => array('update' => 'things.update')
        ));
```

Both should provide the same result, but please note they are not tested.

Answer (score 4):

This work for me

```
Route::match(['put', 'patch'],'thing/{id}', 'ThingsController@update');
```

Comment: This is very similar to the 4 year old accepted answer, but it doesn't answer the question of how to preserve a single route name for both methods.