# Laravel : Resource update MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I saw some people with the same problem but none of the given responses could help me.

I'm currently learning how to use Laravel 5.3 and I have a problem with resources. I've created the following resource in `api.php`:

```
Route::resource('game','GameController',['except' => [
    'create','edit'
]]);
```

So when I call the url `laravel.dev/api/game/3` everything works fine, I get my game formatted in JSON :

```
{
   "type": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "MMO"
    },
    "id": 2,
    "name": "World of Warcraft"
}
```

Same thing with a DELETE request, everything works fine.

But when I try to update my game with a PUT or a PATCH request I get the following exception : [MethodNotAllowedHttpException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz16Y.png) 
.

Here is some more informations that may help you :

Output of the `php artisan route:list` command :

```
POST      | api/game        | game.store   | App\Http\Controllers\GameController@store               
GET|HEAD  | api/game        | game.index   | App\Http\Controllers\GameController@index
GET|HEAD  | api/game/{game} | game.show    | App\Http\Controllers\GameController@show
PUT|PATCH | api/game/{game} | game.update  | App\Http\Controllers\GameController@update
DELETE    | api/game/{game} | game.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\GameController@destroy
```

Code used to make the PUT request :

```
<?php

$client = new http\Client;
$request = new http\Client\Request;

$body = new http\Message\Body;
$body->addForm(array(
    'name' => 'Test update'
), NULL);

$request->setRequestUrl('http://laravel.dev/api/game/3');
$request->setRequestMethod('PUT');
$request->setBody($body);

$request->setHeaders(array(
    'postman-token' => 'f674324c-936b-58bc-606e-98c085f5e851',
    'cache-control' => 'no-cache'
));

$client->enqueue($request)->send();
$response = $client->getResponse();

echo $response->getBody();
```

I hope you could help me

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27316656/laravel-define-a-put-patch-route-as-the-same-route-name

Comment: @saurabhkamble This didn't work for me